# Citing e-books using LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing, ebook

What would be the best way to cite electronic books (e-books) with BibTeX?

I am currently using the biblatex-chicago package to produce footnote references.

I would like to know what entry type and fields should be used.

Comment: I'd just go as with a regular book, since you are citing a physical book that exists (in theory).  It doesn't matter if it is electronic, printed on recycled paper or white paper...

Comment: I agree with @MarioS.E., they are books as any other ones, with authors, publishers etc. As well, if you're not sure how to properly cite an e-book in general (i.e. which fields should the citation have), then the right place to ask is probably [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Since you’re using the `biblatex-chicago` package, I’m guessing that you’re using the Chicago Manual of Style. This [online copy of the guide](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) has the following to say on ebooks:

> If a book is available in more than one format, cite the version you consulted. For books consulted online, list a URL; include an access date only if one is required by your publisher or discipline. If no fixed page numbers are available, you can include a section title or a chapter or other number.

Your entry type should probably be `book`, and with fields to match those listed above. There are several examples in the style guide, so you could model your BibLaTeX after one of those. (I’m not familiar with the `biblatex-chicago` package, so I won’t attempt to reproduce an example in LaTeX.)

If you’re not using the Chicago Manual, then a lot of other major style guides have explanations of how to cite ebooks. For example, here’s [the MLA](http://www.mla.org/style/handbook_faq/cite_an_ebook) and [the APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/06/how-do-you-cite-an-e-book.html) on the subject. In general, you should consult your style guide for ebook citations.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when using `biblatex-chicago`. 
The Chicago style manual says the following about ebooks

> The majority of electronically published books offered for download
>   from a library or bookseller will have a printed counterpart. Because
>   of the potential for differences, however, authors must indicate that
>   they have consulted a format other than print. This indication should
>   be the last part of a full citation that follows the recommendations
>   for citing printed books as detailed throughout this section.
>
> Austen,Jane. Pride and Prejudice. New York: Penguin Classics, 2007.
>   Kindle edition.

Using the Jane Austen example from the manual the best way I found to do it was to use the addendum field which puts kindle edition at the end of the bibliography entry.

```
@book{Austen2007,
address = {New York},
author = {Austen, Jane},
publisher = {Penguin Classics},
title = {{Pride and Prejudice}},
addendum = {Kindle edition},
year = {2007}
}
```

Comment: +1: Never used the `addendum` filed before...seems handy!