# How to cite an epub or ebook with biblatex-dw?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, epub

### Background

Reading so-called *electronic books* is becoming increasingly common, not only as a leisure activity, but also as a serious means to do research. However, there is some reluctance to embrace this format, and one key issue remains the proper citation. Many style manuals simply tend to treat ebooks as books. The problem I've found when they are treated the same (without an indication) is that *citations seem inconsistent*: paper books are cited by page but ebooks (which nobody else will know they are such) will be referred to by chapter/section. In addition, this can be sometimes misleading. For instance, while paraphrasing, the reader can come to believe that I'm alluding a whole chapter/section when I'm not.

Anyway, I haven't found any advise in the BibLaTeX documentation (ver. 3.4): section 3.11.7 refers to Electronic Publishing but it has to do with online archives.

As far as I can tell, there is so far no proper BibLaTeX «field» to indicate the format, a field which could be independently used by any style.

In the meantime, I'd like to find a way to specify that a citation was an ebook. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
    firstfull=true,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Mouffe,
        author = {Mouffe, Chantal},
        title = {Agonistics},
        subtitle = {Thinking the world politically},
        publisher = {Verso},
        year = {2013},
    }
    @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Mouffe}

\cite{Knu86}

\cite{Mouffe}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

#### Expected output

Chantal Mouffe: Agonistics. Thinking the world politically, 2013, epub version

Donald E. Knuth: The TEXbook, 1986

Mouffe: Agonistics

### Question

What entry and field should be used to print an explicit ebook reference under `biblatex-dw`?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119330/17423 answer your questions? Otherwise, I wouldn't say these are really on-topic for the site. They are all opinions.

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't think that answer covers these questions, specially regarding questions 2 & 3: there is no entry sample, as it takes for granted that books and e-books are basically the same. Besides, it doesn't face the problem of question 3.  Maybe I should delete or at least reword  the first question, which invites to opinion-based answers.

Comment: I think QQ. 1 and 3 are off-topic for this site. Q. 2 is surely the same way you would a normal book (which is dependent upon the style you use). Some styles, e.g., ask you to indicate 'print' or 'online' as part of the reference; but an e-book still has a title, author, publisher, etc. There is no 'one (correct) way' to cite even printed materials. Q.3 is an interesting question, so I'll add: as with pre-modern sources (and in recent jurisprudence), the crucial citation is the 'internal' reference: e.g., Bekker numbers for Aristotle & Stephanus pagination for Plato.

Comment: Regarding the edited question: from the `biblatex` 'perspective', the output is 100% dependent upon the style you choose. If the style is not designed to indicate `epub`, it simply will not indicate it. From the style guide 'perspective', then it is purely an issue as to whether the style guide prescriptively demands, casually exhorts, or in some way indicates that it is (not) important to distinguish between printed and electronic versions. As electronic versions of books become more prevalent, the guides will likely make a decision about this over time. But many now do not.

Comment: @jon. Maybe there is no need to distinguish. However, for this distinction not to be important you have to be sure there is a printed version, and that they are the same. On the other hand, I agree with the canonical references, but they are normally no more than a couple of numbers or letters. With ebooks we must produce a whole title, which could be sometimes quite long.

Comment: I don't understand the first two sentences. To be clear: in any particular style *you* are not the one who decides how things must be cited (though you are free to add an explanatory footnote if you feel it is helpful); the journal *Science*, e.g., picks its own rules, not you. In a 'personal style' do whatever you like, of course. As for e-books, the solution needs to be implemented by the publisher for it to work properly. With time, I think this will come. But if you need to follow the *Chicago Manual of Style*, you only need indicate it is an e-book if the style says you must.

Comment: Note also that often the electronic version will include indications of the corresponding printed page (but by no means always). Further: e-versions can easily be searched, so direct quotations should be easy to track down. But there can be no single solution to your question. Note also that in a personal style, you *must implement the feature* if the current style does not cater to it (or adapt a field to that purpose, such as `addendum`).

Comment: I don't use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, but it requires to cite that a book was consulted in a Kindle or whatever version at the end of the reference. APA, on the other hand, asks for a bracketed note [electronic version], etc. I was hoping to find a proper «field entry», but I see there is no such thing.

Comment: Ah, well that's what I was saying! The style you want to use does ask for that '[electronic version]', so your question is actually how to indicate this '[electronic version]' (and how to cite to a section in that electronic version) in the APA style.  This very much on-point for this site, so you should edit your question to reflect the true or underlying question.

Comment: Not really. I'm actually using biblatex-dw for a Philosophy PhD thesis, but there is no model. Anyway, I will change the question to reflect it.

Comment: Mhh maybe *you* could give an example of the kind of ebook you think about. When I recently had to cite one it was just a PDF version of the printed book from the publisher's site, so I cited it as a normal book, but used the online ISBN instead of the print ISBN. It is a matter of the style whether or not to include a note that this is an ebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a universal (style-independent) field to indicate whether a book is an ebook or not.

Most styles support the `note` and `addendum` fields, which you can fill with any text you want. So you could just write `epub version` there. If you see fit, you could also use the `edition` field.

All the ebooks I wanted to cite so far were pretty much digital versions of a print edition and so had normal pages that coincided with the print pages. In that case one would of course give the ebook ISBN.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, only requiring a bracketed note like [ebook] *directly after the title* as in APA-like styles. If you need the note there, the appropriate field to use is `titleaddon`.