# Kindle or Ebooks citations in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, citing, ebook

I am trying to figure out how to cite Kindle or other e-books in a LaTex document.  Any ideas?  Moreover, I would like to cite a specific place in for example a Kindle book - this is typically noted as loc xxx.  Again how would one do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119330/citing-e-books-using-latex

Comment: Welcome! Is Biblatex/Biber an option?